# Регулярные выражения на php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста, с регулярным выражением.

Нужно взять с `https://img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/i4/1739733928/TB2gHIymVXXXXaeXpXXXXXXXXXX_!!1739733928.jpg` только последнее цифры т.е `_!!цифры.jpg`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = 'https://img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/i4/1739733928/TB2gHIymVXXXXaeXpXXXXXXXXXX_!!1739733928.jpg';
preg_match('/(\d+)\D*$/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Результат: `1739733928`

Comment: Спасибо за код =)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не делайте задачи целиком за других людей. Так вы приучаете их лениться и поощряете к тому, чтобы и дальше приходить и требовать готовых решений.

Comment: Человек не знает как составить регулярное выражение для конкретной задачи, мне ему книги рекламировать?

Comment: @Invision проблема в том, что человек по прежнему не знает, как **составить** регулярное выражение для конкретной задачи.